# Importing XML in AS3, FlashPunk & Ogmo, Syntax involving a colon (":")

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

So, I have a game that uses a bunch of tile sheets at different sizes and I decided to write an expanded level loader that would accomodate my insanity.

As far as I can see, the only place the size and type of a layer is saved is in the .oep project file, under the  tag.

```
<LayerDefinitions>
<LayerDefinition xsi:type="GridLayerDefinition">
  <Name>Solids</Name>
  <Grid>
    <Width>24</Width>
    <Height>24</Height>
  </Grid>
  <ScrollFactor>
    <X>1</X>
    <Y>1</Y>
  </ScrollFactor>
  <Color A="255" R="0" G="0" B="0" />
  <ExportMode>Rectangles</ExportMode>
</LayerDefinition>
```

Which is fine, it's easy enough to extract the Name, Width and Height of the grid. What I really need is the TYPE, which is stored in the LayerDefinition tag:

```
<LayerDefinition xsi:type="GridLayerDefinition">
```

The problem is that if I try and grab the @xsi:type attribute, I get an error because of the colon. How can I get around this? How do I nab the .xsi:type attribute? And is the layer TYPE stored somewhere else that I'm not seeing? Current import code:

```
private function loadProject():void
    {
        var curProject:XML = FP.getXML(TESTPROJECT);
        var entry:XML;
        var counter:uint = 0;
        trace("Loading project");
    //  trace(curProject.*);
        for each (entry in curProject.LayerDefinitions)
        {
            trace ("Grid type is: " + entry.@xsi:type);
            trace ("Grid is: " + entry.LayerDefinition.Name);
        }
    }
```

Which yields the error:

```
\src\levelLoader.as(51): col: 41 Error: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before colon.
```

Comment: What's the definition of XSI look like, believe you need to use something like "use namespace xyz" or you need to create a Namespace object and qualify the property with the namespace using :: like, entry.customXSINamespace::type

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `attribute()` method to get values of attributes that conflict with ActionScipt reserved words or syntax.

```
trace("Grid type is: " + entry.attribute("xsi:type"));
```

That should work and give you the value you need. You can check out the `attribute()` method in the AS3 reference [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#attribute%28%29).

Comment: Maybe I'ms mis-formatting my command here, but
   ' private function loadProject():void
  {
   var curProject:XML = FP.getXML(TESTPROJECT);
   var entry:XML;
   var counter:uint = 0;
   trace("Loading project");
  // trace(curProject.*);
   for each (entry in curProject.LayerDefinitions.LayerDefinition)
   {
    //trace("Grid type is: " + entry.attribute("xsi:type"));
    trace("Grid type is: " + entry.attribute("xsi:type"));
    trace ("Grid is: " + entry.Name);
   }
  }'

Doesn't return anything. It does compile. Getting closer!

Comment: Does it return anything, or absolutely nothing at all? If it doesn't even trace the "Grid type is:" part, then there's something wrong with the rest of your code or the XML. One thing that could be causing it is that entry is currently null. Now I don't know much about for each loops but it could be causing it to not run the loop at all and just skip it.